# Prototype - Add class to an element if URL contains a certain value

Tags: prototypejs

I have a radio button, to which I need to add the class "validate-one-required-by-name" using Prototype, but only if the current URL contains the text "/checkout/"

Here's the code for my radio button:

```
<input id="cm1" name="adj[delivery_comment]" value="Ma&ntilde;ana - 10am a 12pm"     title="Ma&ntildeana" class="input-text delivery-comment" type="radio"> <strong>Ma&ntilde;ana</strong> (10am a 12pm)</input>
```

I am very new to prototype, and I've been searchng for days, but I can't find a solution.
Any ideas are welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you do this after the DOM has loaded inside

```
document.observe('dom:loaded',function(){
    //after DOM loaded you can manipulate it

    if(window.location.href.include('/checkout/'))
    {
        //If its one that one radio button you can do it like this
        $('cm1').addClassName('validate-one-required-by-name');

        //lets say its any element with the 'delivery-comment' class
        $$('.delivery-comment').invoke('addClassName','validate-one-required-by-name');

        //or all of the radio buttons in the DOM
        $$('input[type="radio"]').invoke('addClassName','validate-one-required-by-name');
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks! worked like a charm. I'm actually going to use the second option, so thanks for including several ways of doing it.